# Android: How is the appropriate element picked from Cursor in CursorAdapter's newView() method

Tags: android

I wonder how the appropriate element is picked from a Cursor when,

**newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent)** method of the corresponding CursorAdapter object is called as it has no parameter specifying position unlike ArrayAdapter's:

**getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)**  meathod:

Is the data picked from the current row pointed to by the data pointer, or in other words, is the prommer's responsibility that the correct row is being pointed to in the Cursor when newView() method is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cursor based adapter has the `getView` method implemented and this implementation calls the methods `newView()` and `bindView()` to build a view and setup the data **after** setting the cursor to the right position(using the `position` parameter of the getView method).

So the `Cursor` parameter will be pointing to the correct row in the methods `newView` and `bindView` because it will be already set to that position by the `getView` method.

Comment: Thanks buddy, you just answered what i wanted to know. That's what i wanted to know that how the hell is that thing(Cursor pointing to proper row) taken care of. Next time i will dig deeper into documentations and source codes before asking such questions

Answer (score 0):

Form your Cursor according to your requirement. That means when you execute a query put some condition in it and it will returns the cursor according to that.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need current position of view in list in cursor adapter.
Cause CursorAdapter move position automatically. But if you stil want to fetch row number, you can do by following method:

```
cursor.getPosition();
```

Comment: Do u mean to say that if, let's say, 15th row of a ListView which is bound to a Cursor by a CursorAdapter, is to be populated, then automatically, 15th row's data in the Cursor will be returned by getString() called inside the newView() method?

Comment: yes, but instead of newView use bindView to popualte list item from cursor.